# Add additional property to an observable

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

Can someone help me out with Observables, I am trying to return 2 things in an observable i.e. call a service to upload a file and get back the percentage complete as an observable.  Once that is completed I also want access to another property i.e. the download URL that came from the same service call.

**SERVICE**

```
pushFileToStorage(fileUpload: FileUpload): Observable<number | undefined> {
    const filePath = `${this.basePath}/${fileUpload.file.name}`;
    const storageRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);

    const uploadTask = this.storage.upload(filePath, fileUpload.file);
    uploadTask
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          storageRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((downloadURL) => {
            fileUpload.url = downloadURL;
            fileUpload.name = fileUpload.file.name;
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe();

    return uploadTask.percentageChanges();
  }
```

Currently I am getting the percent change back here return uploadTask.percentageChanges();, however i also want the fileUpload.url = downloadURL sent back with the percent change so i have access to it once completed.

**Call to Service**

```
this._firestoreStorageService
          .pushFileToStorage(this.currentFileUpload)
          .subscribe(
            (percentage) => {
              debugger;
              this.percentage = Math.round(percentage ? percentage : 0);
              // When this is 100% i want to be able to assign the download URL to update on a user profile
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log(error);
            }
          );
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be something like this (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge):

```
const obs$1 = uploadTask.snapshotChanges().pipe(mergeMap(() => storageRef.getDownloadURL()), map(url => ({percentage: 100, url})));
const obs$2 = uploadTask.percentageChanges().map(percentage => {{percentage}})
return merge(obs$1, obs$2)
```

(Not sure about your finalize block -- upload failed but u want to update url huh?)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Petr-Averyanov

I had some issues getting type compiling with that and it seemed I had to call both methods separately to subscribe to them.

However I took your ideas and re-wrote it and ended up with the following:

**Service**

```
uploadFileAndGetMetadata(
    mediaFolderPath: string,
    fileToUpload: File
  ): FilesUploadMetadata {
  
  const { name } = fileToUpload;
    const filePath = `${mediaFolderPath}/${new Date().getTime()}_${name}`;
    const uploadTask: AngularFireUploadTask = this.storage.upload(
      filePath,
      fileToUpload
    );
    return {
      uploadProgress$: uploadTask.percentageChanges(),
      downloadUrl$: this.getDownloadUrl$(uploadTask, filePath),
    };
  }
  private getDownloadUrl$(
    uploadTask: AngularFireUploadTask,
    path: string
  ): Observable<string> {
    return from(uploadTask).pipe(
      switchMap((_) => this.storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL())
    );
  }
```

**Component**

percentage: number;

**In the upload File Method**

```
let uploadFile$ =   this._firestoreStorageService.uploadFileAndGetMetadata('upload', file);
uploadFile$.downloadUrl$.subscribe((downloadUrl) => this.mainForm.patchValue({ picture: downloadUrl }) );
       uploadFile$.uploadProgress$.subscribe((uploadProgress) => {this.percentage = uploadProgress;
        });
```